# Scroll to an html element with a particular id in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, scroll

I have html elements with id's assigned.  Now I want to scroll to those elements.  I see jQuery has a scrollTop which takes an integer value..  How do I easily just make a particular html element with an id scroll to the top?  Ideally, with nice and smooth animation.

A quick search showed many scrolling plugins... if a plugin is needed for the above functionality, what's the most popular one?  I'm also using jquery-ui.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use something like this to scroll to `#someElement` when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#someElement").offset().top}, 1000); 
});
```

It simply animates the `scrollTop` property of the `body` element, and uses the top offset of some specific element as the position to scroll to. The animation lasts for 1000ms.

Note: it selects both `html` and `body` so it works across browsers. I'm not sure on the specifics, but some quick tests show that Chrome uses `body`, but Firefox and IE use `html`.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/68Msz/1/).

Answer (score 0):

**Consider the following snippet:**

```
$('#myDiv').bind('click',function(){

    var pos = $(this).offset().top,
    scrollSpeed = 2;

    for (var i = pos; i > 0; i=i-scrollSpeed) {
        $(window).scrollTop(i);
    }
});
```

It scrolling was binded to #myDiv element on click just for example. Code determines a position of #myDiv element, than calculates number of scroll steps (speed/smoothness). Than does jQuery .scrollTop() thing.