# Navigating to page fragment with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, fragment

Clicking an `<a href="#location" />` link navigates to the element with `id = location`, correct? Is there a way to navigate to the element with `id = location` in a similar fashion as clicking the link but using javascript? I know I can just find the link and simulate a click on it with javascript, but I'm curious is there is another way to do it.

Comment: This question has solutions using jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236848/scroll-to-an-html-element-with-a-particular-id-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: This one uses vanilla javascript: http://cgd.io/2008/using-javascript-to-scroll-to-a-specific-elementobject/